# To retrieve each row from dataset and write each row to a text file

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, dataset, console-application

I'm calling a Stored Procedure say 'GetUserDetails' which retrieves say 3 rows 3 columns (3X3) with SqlCommand and this is stored in to a DataSet.

Now I wanted to loop through each row from the DataSet and write each row to a separate text file, I mean the final outcome should contain 3 text file which contains only a row of data from the dataset  and save it in some location.

can anyone help at it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add the snippet for your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(...))
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
using (var file = new StreamWriter("result.txt"))
while (dr.Read())
{
    file.WriteLine(dr[0].ToString() + " " + dr[1].ToString() + " " + dr[2].ToString());
}
```